# FUSION Microsoft visual runtime library C++ blank error

Tags: lidar, fusion

I am trying to run the DTM script on 73 laz files (each file >500 MB) and a big single ground filter.laz file > 1 GB that has 303239327 points. The laz files ran just fine with the ground filter script, but as soon as the DTM script begins to read the ground filter file, I get this error. I have a feeling that this is happening due to a memory/CPU processing issue, although upon checking the load,the task manager only shows around 2 GB of RAM in use by FUSION and 54% single core use on an i7. The DTM script otherwise runs fine on smaller size ground filter file. Is there a way to allocate more resources to FUSION? I usually run the batch file through Notepad++. Should I try LTK.exe for this particular script on a big ground filter laz file? In case the script is needed, it is as follows:

```
:: FUSION/LDV
set FUSION_DIR=%FUSION_DIR%;C:\FUSION\;

:: LAZ file 
set LAZ_DIR=D:\LAS_Files\laz

:: Processing
set PROC_DIR=C:\03_processing
cd %PROC_DIR%

:: Project Name
set PROJ=ABCD

:: #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
:: # B) ############ Processing #############
:: #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

:: 3) # Digital terrain model (DTM): Gridded surface model using collections of random points.
mkDir 03_dtm
C:\FUSION\GridSurfaceCreate /smooth:5 %PROC_DIR%\03_dtm\%PROJ%_dtm.dtm 1 M M 1 11 2 2 %PROC_DIR%\02_groundfilter\%PROJ%_ground.laz
C:\FUSION\dtm2ascii %PROC_DIR%\03_dtm\%PROJ%_dtm.dtm

CMD /k
```

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

It seems to be a Microsoft visual runtime error

Comment: Moderator can I delete this question or can you delete this? As after troubleshooting, it turns out the issue is related to Windows 10 update, so this error has nothing to do with LiDAR and Fusion, as the script is currently running fine in safe mode. So I will contact Microsoft about this. Also, will deleting a question lower my rating?

Comment: Actually it turns out it's not a Windows 10 issue, but rather a limitation of 32-bit Fusion batch scripts while handing bigger data. Use the 64-bit version of the .exe files in Fusion version 4, and this error won't arise.